# Conflicting HDF5 versions from system and a conda environment with h5py

Tags: c++, cmake, anaconda, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to compile C++ code that requires HDF5. I am also using a conda environment to manage packages required for post-processing in Python, and for starting parameter combination runs that call the C++ based executable. This conda env contains h5py and additional HDF5 distribution in addition to the one installed on the system.

CMake is able to configure correctly, and building in the base environment works. However, when building *in the conda environment with h5py activated* (which is required for calling the executable for parameter combination runs), I end up with the following error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable simulation
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_global_init@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_slist_free_all@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_slist_append@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/simulation.dir/build.make:597: src/simulation] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2032: src/CMakeFiles/simulation.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2039: src/CMakeFiles/simulation.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:963: simulation] Error 2
```

Configuring with `cmake -B./build/` in the activated conda env works, but finds the wrong HDF5 version (the system version, not the h5py version):

```
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: /home/path/to/my/env
-- HDF5 CXX compiler wrapper is unable to compile a minimal HDF5 program.
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so (found version "1.10.7") found components: CXX 
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.74.0")  
-- HDF5 C compiler wrapper is unable to compile a minimal HDF5 program.
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so (found version "1.10.7")  
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found version "1.74.0") found components: system serialization 
CMake Warning at build/_deps/highfive-src/CMakeLists.txt:117 (message):
  Unit tests have been DISABLED.


-- Detected CPPZMQ Version - 4.10.0
-- cppzmq v4.10.0
-- Using the multi-header code from /home/path/to/my/env/build/_deps/json-src/include/
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/path/to/my/env/build
```

Running `h5cc -showconfig` when the conda env is activated shows, that the HDF5 version 1.14.2 coming with h5py is in use:

```
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.14.2
                  Configured on: Sun Aug 20 20:09:14 UTC 2023
                  Configured by: conda@8701a29b7fa1
                    Host system: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
              Uname information: Linux 8701a29b7fa1 5.15.0-1041-azure #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 20 20:34:08 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
                       Byte sex: little-endian
             Installation point: /home/path/to/my/env

Compiling Options:
------------------
                     Build Mode: production
              Debugging Symbols: no
                        Asserts: no
                      Profiling: no
             Optimization Level: high

Linking Options:
----------------
                      Libraries: shared
  Statically Linked Executables: 
                        LDFLAGS: -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,-rpath,/home/path/to/my/envlib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/path/to/my/envlib -L/home/path/to/my/envlib
                     H5_LDFLAGS: 
                     AM_LDFLAGS:  -L/home/path/to/my/envlib -L/home/path/to/my/envlib
                Extra libraries: -lcrypto -lcurl -lpthread -lsz -lz -ldl -lm 
                       Archiver: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ar
                       AR_FLAGS: cr
                         Ranlib: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ranlib

Languages:
----------
                              C: yes
                     C Compiler: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc
                       CPPFLAGS: -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/path/to/my/envinclude
                    H5_CPPFLAGS: -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L   -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API -I/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/work/src/H5FDsubfiling
                    AM_CPPFLAGS:  -I/home/path/to/my/envinclude -I/home/path/to/my/envinclude
                        C Flags: -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/path/to/my/envinclude -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/work=/usr/local/src/conda/hdf5-1.14.2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/path/to/my/env=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix
                     H5 C Flags:  -std=c99  -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wno-c++-compat -Wlarger-than=2560 -Wlogical-op -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wsync-nand -Wno-unsuffixed-float-constants -Wdouble-promotion -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wdate-time -Warray-bounds=2 -Wc99-c11-compat -Wduplicated-cond -Whsa -Wnormalized -Wnull-dereference -Wunused-const-variable -Walloca -Walloc-zero -Wduplicated-branches -Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=1 -Wattribute-alias -Wcast-align=strict -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wattribute-alias=2 -Wmissing-profile -Wc11-c2x-compat -fstdarg-opt -fdiagnostics-urls=never -fno-diagnostics-color -s  -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wformat -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wint-to-pointer-cast -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-sign -Wpointer-to-int-cast -Wredundant-decls -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wunused-variable -Wunused-function -Wunused-parameter -Wincompatible-pointer-types -Wint-conversion -Wshadow -Wrestrict -Wcast-function-type -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wno-aggregate-return -Wno-inline -Wno-missing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-noreturn -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-jump-misses-init -Wstrict-overflow=2 -Wno-suggest-attribute=const -Wno-suggest-attribute=noreturn -Wno-suggest-attribute=pure -Wno-suggest-attribute=format -Wno-suggest-attribute=cold -Wno-suggest-attribute=malloc -O3
                     AM C Flags: 
               Shared C Library: yes
               Static C Library: no


                        Fortran: yes
               Fortran Compiler: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gfortran
                  Fortran Flags: 
               H5 Fortran Flags:  -std=f2008  -Waliasing -Wall -Wcharacter-truncation -Wextra -Wimplicit-interface -Wsurprising -Wunderflow -pedantic -Wintrinsics-std -Wimplicit-procedure -Wreal-q-constant -Wfunction-elimination -Wrealloc-lhs -Wrealloc-lhs-all -Wno-c-binding-type -Winteger-division -Wfrontend-loop-interchange  -fdiagnostics-urls=never -fno-diagnostics-color -s  -Wno-unused-dummy-argument -Wno-array-temporaries -O3
               AM Fortran Flags: 
         Shared Fortran Library: yes
         Static Fortran Library: no
               Module Directory: ${includedir}

                            C++: yes
                   C++ Compiler: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++
                      C++ Flags: -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/path/to/my/envinclude -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/hdf5_1692561980689/work=/usr/local/src/conda/hdf5-1.14.2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/path/to/my/env=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix
                   H5 C++ Flags:   -std=c++11 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wreorder -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wlarger-than=2560 -Wlogical-op -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wsync-nand -Wdouble-promotion -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wdate-time -Wopenmp-simd -Warray-bounds=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Whsa -Wnormalized -Wnull-dereference -Wunused-const-variable -Walloca -Walloc-zero -Wduplicated-branches -Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=1 -Wattribute-alias -Wcast-align=strict -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wattribute-alias=2 -Wmissing-profile -Wno-deprecated-copy -fstdarg-opt -fdiagnostics-urls=never -fno-diagnostics-color -s  -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wswitch -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wshadow -O3
                   AM C++ Flags: 
             Shared C++ Library: yes
             Static C++ Library: no

                           Java: no


Features:
---------
                     Parallel HDF5: no
  Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: no
                Large Parallel I/O: no
                High-level library: yes
Dimension scales w/ new references: no
                  Build HDF5 Tests: yes
                  Build HDF5 Tools: yes
                   Build GIF Tools: yes
                      Threadsafety: yes
               Default API mapping: v114
    With deprecated public symbols: yes
            I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib),szip(encoder)
                     Map (H5M) API: no
                        Direct VFD: yes
                        Mirror VFD: no
                     Subfiling VFD: no
                (Read-Only) S3 VFD: yes
              (Read-Only) HDFS VFD: no
    Packages w/ extra debug output: none
                       API tracing: no
              Using memory checker: yes
            Function stack tracing: no
                  Use file locking: best-effort
         Strict file format checks: no
      Optimization instrumentation: no
```

When the conda env is deactivated and only the base env is activated, the version is 1.10.7:

```
SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.10.7
                  Configured on: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 23:33:27 +0000
                  Configured by: Debian
                    Host system: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
              Uname information: Debian
                       Byte sex: little-endian
             Installation point: /usr
            Flavor name: serial

Compiling Options:
------------------
                     Build Mode: production
              Debugging Symbols: no
                        Asserts: no
                      Profiling: no
             Optimization Level: high

Linking Options:
----------------
                      Libraries: static, shared
  Statically Linked Executables: 
                        LDFLAGS: -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro
                     H5_LDFLAGS: -Wl,--version-script,$(top_srcdir)/debian/map_serial.ver
                     AM_LDFLAGS: 
                Extra libraries: -lcrypto -lcurl -lpthread -lsz -lz -ldl -lm 
                       Archiver: ar
                       AR_FLAGS: cr
                         Ranlib: x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib

Languages:
----------
                              C: yes
                     C Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
                       CPPFLAGS: -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
                    H5_CPPFLAGS: -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L   -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API
                    AM_CPPFLAGS: 
                        C Flags: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=$(top_srcdir)=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
                     H5 C Flags:  -std=c99  -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-c++-compat -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wlarger-than=2560 -Wlogical-op -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wsync-nand -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wno-unsuffixed-float-constants -Wdouble-promotion -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wdate-time -Warray-bounds=2 -Wc99-c11-compat -Wduplicated-cond -Whsa -Wnormalized -Wnull-dereference -Wunused-const-variable -Walloca -Walloc-zero -Wduplicated-branches -Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=1 -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wrestrict -Wattribute-alias -Wcast-align=strict -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wattribute-alias=2 -Wmissing-profile -fstdarg-opt -s -Wno-aggregate-return -Wno-inline -Wno-missing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-noreturn -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-jump-misses-init -Wno-suggest-attribute=const -Wno-suggest-attribute=noreturn -Wno-suggest-attribute=pure -Wno-suggest-attribute=format -Wno-suggest-attribute=cold -Wno-suggest-attribute=malloc -O3  -Werror=bad-function-cast -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=missing-declarations -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=nested-externs -Werror=old-style-definition -Werror=packed -Werror=pointer-sign -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=redundant-decls -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=switch -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wcast-align -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wformat -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=shadow -Wcast-function-type -Wmaybe-uninitialized
                     AM C Flags: 
               Shared C Library: yes
               Static C Library: yes


                        Fortran: yes
               Fortran Compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
                  Fortran Flags: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=$(top_srcdir)=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong
               H5 Fortran Flags:  -std=f2008  -Waliasing -Wall -Wcharacter-truncation -Wextra -Wimplicit-interface -Wsurprising -Wunderflow -pedantic -Warray-temporaries -Wintrinsics-std -Wimplicit-procedure -Wreal-q-constant -Wfunction-elimination -Wrealloc-lhs -Wrealloc-lhs-all -Wno-c-binding-type -Wuse-without-only -Winteger-division -Wfrontend-loop-interchange  -s -O3
               AM Fortran Flags: 
         Shared Fortran Library: yes
         Static Fortran Library: yes

                            C++: yes
                   C++ Compiler: /usr/bin/g++
                      C++ Flags: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=$(top_srcdir)=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
                   H5 C++ Flags:   -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wreorder -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wlarger-than=2560 -Wlogical-op -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wsync-nand -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wno-unsuffixed-float-constants -Wdouble-promotion -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wdate-time -Wopenmp-simd -Warray-bounds=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Whsa -Wnormalized -Wnull-dereference -Wunused-const-variable -Walloca -Walloc-zero -Wduplicated-branches -Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=1 -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wrestrict -Wattribute-alias -Wcast-align=strict -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wattribute-alias=2 -Wmissing-profile -fstdarg-opt -s -O3  -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Werror=packed -Werror=redundant-decls -Werror=switch -Wunused-but-set-variable -Werror=unused-function -Werror=unused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Werror=shadow
                   AM C++ Flags: 
             Shared C++ Library: yes
             Static C++ Library: yes

                           Java: yes
                  Java Compiler: /usr/bin/java (openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19)


Features:
---------
                   Parallel HDF5: no
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: no
              Large Parallel I/O: no
              High-level library: yes
                Build HDF5 Tests: yes
                Build HDF5 Tools: yes
                    Threadsafety: yes
             Default API mapping: v18
  With deprecated public symbols: yes
          I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib),szip(encoder)
                             MPE: no
                      Direct VFD: no
                      Mirror VFD: no
              (Read-Only) S3 VFD: yes
            (Read-Only) HDFS VFD: no
                         dmalloc: no
  Packages w/ extra debug output: none
                     API tracing: no
            Using memory checker: no
 Memory allocation sanity checks: no
          Function stack tracing: no
                Use file locking: best-effort
       Strict file format checks: no
    Optimization instrumentation: no
```

In my CMakeLists.txt I am using the following relevant lines:

```
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS CXX)
link_directories(${HDF5_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})

...


#### COMPILER FLAGS ###
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++2a")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp -larmadillo -lhdf5")  # required for mlpack
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ljson")  # required for SwarmRL integration
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -march=native")  # optimized
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Wformat-truncation -Wundef -fno-common -Wconversion -Wmisleading-indentation")  # debugging
# other flags: -Wshadow
```

Adding the `-lcurl` flag did not help.

My relevant CMakeCache.txt parts looks like this, indicating that the version 1.10 paths are set (and not the 1.14 paths!):

```
//HDF5 CXX Wrapper compiler.  Used only to detect HDF5 compile
// flags.
HDF5_CXX_COMPILER_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/h5c++

//Path to a file.
HDF5_CXX_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/hdf5/serial

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_crypto:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_curl:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_dl:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_hdf5:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_hdf5_cpp:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_m:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_pthread:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_sz:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_z:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
```

Conda environment:

```
name: myenv
channels:  # strict channel priority enforced! order matters
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - snakemake=7.32
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - seaborn
  - scipy
  - yaml
  - pyyaml
  - graphviz
  - ffmpeg
  - numba
  - h5py
  - pytables
  - jupyter
```

I suspect that the cmake configuration HDF5 version (1.10.7) does not match the one that is active due to the conda env (1.14.2). I somehow need to specify in CMake which HDF5 libraries to use I guess.
Ideally I could use the version that comes with h5py, to have a better dependency management I think.
How can I solve this (in the most elegant way)?

Thank you for your help!

---

Update 1: I managed to resolve the error by downgrading my HDF5 version coming with h5py.
To do so, I am using

```
  - hdf5=1.10.6
  - h5py=3.7
```

with channel priority flexible (it does not work with strict channel priority, does anyone know why?).
This indicates that the problem is indeed the mismatch between the conda HDF5 version and the system HDF5 version.

Using one common HDF5 version however would be great, looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are dealing with a conflict between the system HDF5 library (version 1.10.7) and the HDF5 library included in your conda environment (version 1.14.2). To resolve this issue, you need to make sure that CMake uses the HDF5 library from your conda environment when building your project. You can achieve this by setting appropriate CMake variables.

Here's how you can do it:

1.Set the HDF5_ROOT CMake variable to point to the HDF5 installation in your conda environment. You can set this variable before running CMake.
bash

> ```
> cmake -B./build/ -DHDF5_ROOT=/path/to/your/conda/env
> ```

Replace /path/to/your/conda/env with the actual path to your conda environment.

2. Make sure that your conda environment is activated when you run CMake and build your project. This ensures that CMake will find and use the HDF5 library and headers from the activated environment.
   Here's the complete workflow:

> ```
> Activate your conda environment*
> conda activate myenv
>
>  
> *Run CMake with the HDF5_ROOT variable set*
> cmake -B./build/ -DHDF5_ROOT=/path/to/your/conda/env
>
> * Build your project*
> cmake --build ./build/
> ```

This approach should ensure that CMake uses the HDF5 library from your conda environment rather than the system HDF5 library.

If you encounter any further issues, you might need to adjust other CMake variables, such as HDF5_CXX_INCLUDE_DIR and HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY, to point to the correct locations within your conda environment.

By setting these variables appropriately, you can ensure that CMake uses the HDF5 version provided by your conda environment, allowing you to manage the dependency more effectively.

Comment: I tried your solution, but despite setting the flag cmake still finds the system HDF5 version, and not the other version:
`-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so (found version "1.10.7") found components: CXX 
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.74.0")  `

Comment: I guess you are referring to this documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindHDF5.html